# Possible to assign $this to a new class instance?

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

is it possible to assign the $this object to a new instance of a class that extends the $this base class?? ( in php of course )

```
class base {

    function a() {

        // do some stuff here
        $extended = new extending();
        $this = $extended;
        $this->extended_functionality();
    }
}

class extending {

    function extended_functionality() {

        // do some more! stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: That's an anti-pattern. Regardless of whether its possible or not, I would recomend you avoid it.

Comment: Hmm did some more testing and looks like you cant do it... maybe someone can direct me to a more semantic approach?

Comment: Too long winded the explination why im trying to do this. but in short i know its wrong. and in short here is the problem:

Im trying to instantiate classes dynamically from value of a database field and although im just trying to reuse and centralise my code. with further thinking i solved it.

Comment: if someone would like to add an answer of why you cant o it i will select it as the answer so people can find this question / answer

Comment: For anyone who does find this, please, for the love of GOD don't try to re-assign $this. It's about as un-friendly as you can get for other people coming in to maintain your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Short... No.

`$this` is a read-only keyword that represents the current instantiated object.

Just create the object you mean to in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should:

```
class base {

private extended;

    function a() {

        // do some stuff here
        $this->extended = new extending();
        $this->extended->extended_functionality();
    }
}

class extending {

    function __construct() {
    }

    function extended_functionality() {

        // do some more! stuff here
    }
}
```